Connection between dihedral angles of regular polyhedron and eigenvalues of adjacency matrix of its faces
I was searching for a simple method of calculating dihedral angles of regular polyhedra (actually I am interested only in ${\mathbb{E}^3}$) and found this answer very interesting.
It states that the desired dihedral angle $\alpha$ of given regular polyhedron $P$ can be found using this formula: $$\alpha = \cos^{-1}\!\Big(\frac{\theta_2}{\mathrm{deg}(G^\circ)}\Big)$$
where:

$P'$ is dual polyhedron to $P$
$G^\circ$ is edge-graph of $P'$
$ \theta_2$ is second largest eigenvalue of adjacency matrix of $G^\circ$
$\mathrm{deg}(G^\circ)$ is the vertex-degree of $G^\circ$.

I am wondering how this formula can be derived?
I can notice that if we choose some point $O$ inside $P$ (for convinience, let $O$ be center of $P$ and also center of our coordinate system) and consider set of perpendiculars from point $O$ to faces of $P$ then we get system of unit vectors $V=\{v_{1},...,v_{n}\}$in $\mathbb{E}^3$. Then dihedral angles of $P$ are complements to $\pi$ to angles between corresponding perpendiculars $v_i, v_j$ and initial problem seems equivalent to finding angles between "evenly" spaced $n$ vectors $v_1...v_n$ (which correspond to evenly spaced $n$ points on unit shpere). These points also correspond to vertices of $P'$. That is why it is probably useful to consider $P'$.
But next steps of the solution are not so clear to me.
In partiсular: how do we know that we should consider eigenvalues of adjacency matrix of $G^\circ$, what is their geometrical meaning in terms of our problem and what is so special about second largest of them?
I am not familiar with graph theory yet so maybe I am missing some basic properties of adjacency matrices of graphs, and I would be grateful for advice on books that can shed light on solution this problem.
